# Using 'AND' and 'OR' in same mysql statement with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

Is it possible to do this?

Lets say I have a table : `data`

```
$id_1 = "checking";
$id_2 = "box";
$id_users = 1;

id    id_1        id_2         id_users
1     checking    box             1
2     checking    circle          1
3     box         checking        1
4     box         checking        1

$sql = $db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM data WHERE ((id_1 = ? AND id_2= ?) OR (id_1 = ? AND id_2 = ?)) AND id_users = ?");
$sql -> execute(array($id_1, $id_2, $id_2, $id_1, $id_users));
echo count($sql);
```

With this, I'm getting an output of 1 only. Technically I should be getting an output of 3, correct? Because there are 3 possibilities with checking and box.

The SQL is supposed to check either table for the two combinations of `checking` and `box`.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: `(id_1 = ? AND id_2)` is intentional or should it be `(id_1 = ? AND id_2 = ?)`

Comment: sorry, it was a typo. it should be id_2 = ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What MДΓΓ БДLL said is ok, but you could also use named parameters:

```
$sql = $db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM data WHERE ((id_1 = :id1 AND id_2= :id2) OR (id_1 = :id2 AND id_2 = :id1)) AND id_users = :idusers");
$sql -> execute(array(':id1' => $id_1, ':id2' => $id_2, ':idusers' => $id_users));
```

And you need to fetch result

```
$result = $sql->fetch();
echo $result[0];
```

Comment: The problem with your statement, is that $id_1 is going to equal id_1.

Comment: My bad, soon in the morning and no cofee yet :), gonna switch it

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're [`count()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php)ing the already-counted SQL `COUNT`ed number of rows.
How about just `echo $sql`?

```
$sql = $db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM data WHERE ((id_1 = ? AND id_2= ?) OR (id_1 = ? AND id_2)) AND id_users = ?");
$sql->execute(array($id_1, $id_2, $id_2, $id_1, $id_users));
echo $sql->fetch();
```

Comment: Now I'm getting an error : `catchable fatal error: object of class PDOStatement could not be converted to string...
`

Comment: `echo $sql` is not right, you have to fetch it with `$sql->fetch()`

Answer (score 1):

In your query it seems that you are passing id_1 as parameter to id_2 and id_2 parameter as id_1 so as per your query there is only one combination of `id_1 = checking`  and `id_2 = box` ,
so you are getting output count as 1
instead of this to avoid parameter confusion use

```
$sql -> execute(array(':id1' => $id_1, ':id2' => $id_2, ':idusers' => $id_users));
```